# If Statement enable / disable

Tags: php, if-statement

So i have a stop / renew button which if enabled = 1 if disabled = 0

But i get this.

```
Notice: Undefined variable: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\stress.php on line 370
```

How would i define that when it's already called?

```
<?php

    $SQLSelect = $odb->query("SELECT * FROM `logs` WHERE user='{$_SESSION['username']}' ORDER BY `date` DESC");
    while ($show = $SQLSelect->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $ip = htmlspecialchars($show['ip']);
        $port = htmlspecialchars($show['port']);
        $time = htmlspecialchars($show['time']);        
        $method = htmlspecialchars($show['method']);
        $rowID = htmlspecialchars($show['id']);
        $date = htmlspecialchars($show['date']);
        $expires = htmlspecialchars($date + $time - time());

        if ($expires < 0 || $show['stopped'] != 0) {
            $countdown = "Expired";
        }
        else {
            $countdown = '<div id="a' . $rowID . '"></div>';
            echo "
                <script id='ajax'>
                    var count={$expires};
                    var counter=setInterval(a{$rowID}, 1000);
                    function a{$rowID}(){
                        count=count-1;
                        if (count <= 0){
                            clearInterval(counter);
                            attacks();
                            return;
                        }
                    document.getElementById('a{$rowID}').innerHTML=count;
                    }
                </script>
            ";
        }

        if ($show['time'] + $show['date'] > time() and $show['stopped'] != 1) {
            if($stop == 1){ $action = '<form method="post" action=""><button type="submit" name="stopbtn" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-power-off"></i> Stop</button>'; } else { $stop = ''; }
                                                    } else {
            if($renew == 1){ $action = '<button type="submit" name="attackBtn" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Renew</button>
                                                    <input name="host" type="hidden" value="' . htmlspecialchars($ip) . '"/>
                                                    <input name="port" type="hidden" value="' . htmlspecialchars($port) . '"/>
                                                    <input name="time" type="hidden" value="' . htmlspecialchars($time) . '"/>
                                                    <input name="method" type="hidden" value="' . htmlspecialchars($method) . '"/>
                                            </form>'; } else { $renew = ''; }

    if($renew == 0 && $stop == 0){ $disableds = 'Disabled'; } else { $disableds = ''; }

        }
        echo '<tr>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">' . htmlspecialchars($rowID) . '</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">' . htmlspecialchars($ip) . '</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">' . htmlspecialchars($port) . '</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">' . htmlspecialchars($time) . ' Seconds</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">' . htmlspecialchars($method) . '</td>             
        <td style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($countdown) . '</td>
        <td style="font-size: 12px;" class="text-center">' . htmlspecialchars_decode($action) . '</td>
        </tr>';
    }
?>
```

I'm lost on what I've missed out because it look fine to me but clearly i've missed something

Edited: uploaded the full php code rather than if statements hopefully this helps resolve issues.

Comment: is it complete code? because I can see missing if else statements.

Comment: i'd recomend using switch instead of so many ifs :o

Comment: i'll edit and upload the whole code sorry  ddn't think it was relevant.

Comment: define `$action = '';` before your if statement.

Comment: And what is switch may i ask im more common with If statements

Comment: "define $action = ''; before your if statement." i used exact way on a purchase page it works flawless but because this is stop / renew makes it more difficult.

Comment: don't add `define` word just `$action = '';`

Comment: okay done that now both of the stop / renew works but 
Notice: Undefined variable: action in C:\xampp\htdocs\stress.php on line 369

on 

 if($stop == 0 && $renew == 0){ $disableds = 'Disabled'; } else { $disableds = ''; }
isn't working when enabled = 1 in db show's the buttons fine. 

when its disabled = 0 it doesn't show Disabled! gives undefined error